# How to check which database column returns data and process the MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench, database-trigger

I have 3 SQL Update statements. Those are calling from an application.

**1st UPDATE QUERY**

```
//only update rel column
UPDATE db1.data SET rel = 'x' WHERE tID = 'some value';
```

**2nd UPDATE QUERY**

```
//here there is no endDate field
UPDATE db1.data SET action = 'some value' status = 'some value' startDate = 'some value' type = 'some value' WHERE tID = 'some value';
```

**3rd UPDATE QUERY**

```
//but here it is endDate
UPDATE db1.data SET action = 'some value' status = 'some value' startDate = 'some value' endDate = 'some value' type = 'some value' WHERE tID = 'some value';
```

And also what I am doing is, there is another database called `db2`. So when `db1` updated using those update queries I need to update `db2.data` table also. So I am creating a trigger using `MySQL Workbench`.

Here is the Trigger,

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `db1`.`data_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `data` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.rel<> OLD.rel/*= 'x'*/ THEN
UPDATE db2.data
SET rel = NEW.rel
WHERE tID = NEW.tID;
END IF;
END
```

I am stuck here with how to check which column returns data. How can I create Trigger for accomplishing this without getting any `NULL` Error?

Basically what I need is,

```
if NEW.rel <> OLD.rel run this -> UPDATE db2.data SET rel = NEW.rel WHERE tID = NEW.tID;

if data returns with this column `endDate` I need to do this -> UPDATE db1.data SET action = 'some value' status = 'some value' startDate = 'some value' endDate = 'some value' type = 'some value' WHERE tID = 'some value';

and if not returning values for `endDate` I need to run this -> UPDATE db1.data SET action = 'some value' status = 'some value' startDate = 'some value' type = 'some value' WHERE tID = 'some value';
```

> In my `Trigger`, It's only updating `1st UPDATE Query`. But I need to
>   run `2nd and 3rd UPDATE Queries` also in the `Trigger`. So how can I do
>   it? Is there any validation that I can do to avoid `NULL Error`.
>   Because if DB updates only `rel` I need to update `rel` only. So How can I know that what is updating?  If DB
>   updates with `endDate` I need to run `3rd UPDATE Query`. If DB updates without `endDate` I need to run `2rd UPDATE Query`. That's what I need.
>
> I need to do all in one Trigger using `ELSE IF` or anything better.

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question doesn't really seem to make sense... what does *"which column returns data"* mean?  This is an update trigger... nothing "returns" anything.

Comment: `which column means` If database updated only the `flag` I need to update `flag` only. And if database updated with `endDate` I need to update this `UPDATE db2.data SET action = 'some value' status = 'some value' startDate = 'some value' type = 'some value' WHERE tID = 'some value';`. And if there is no `endDate` I need to update this `UPDATE db2.data SET action = 'some value' status = 'some value' startDate = 'some value' endDate = 'some value' type = 'some value' WHERE tID = 'some value';` So how can I make that validation in Trigger to avoid any `NULL` Error? @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot How can I do that? Can you help me?

Comment: The main question, are what are you trying to do. Your trigger is correctly defined. If you update the "rel" column, then these value are updated on db2.data. If you didn't update these column, trigger ends. And as @Michael-sqlbot tolds you, a update or a update trigger didn't return anything. I can see this: Or your explanation are incorrect, or the code are incorrect.

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto Yes, the question title may be incorrect but I don't know how to explain what I need in the title. I have updated my question also. In my `Trigger` It's only updating `1st UPDATE Query`. But I need to run `2nd and 3rd UPDATE Query` also in the `Trigger`. So how can I do it? Is there any validation that I can do to avoid `NULL Error`. Because if `DB` updates only `rel` I need to update only`rel`. If `DB` updates with `endDate` or without `endDate` I need to update all related to that. That's what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understand correctly, you need to update your db2 only if rel field is updated, and do some more updates if you got a endDate on your UPDATE query.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `db1`.`data_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `data` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF OLD.rel <> NEW.rel THEN
 UPDATE db2.data SET rel = NEW.rel WHERE tID = NEW.tID;
 IF OLD.endDate = NEW.endDate OR NEW.endDate IS NULL THEN
  UPDATE db1.data SET action = 'some value' status = 'some value' startDate = 'some value' type = 'some value' WHERE tID = NEW.tID;
 ELSE
  UPDATE db1.data SET action = 'some value' status = 'some value' startDate = 'some value' endDate = 'some value' type = 'some value' WHERE tID = NEW.tID;
 END IF;
END IF;
END
```

I hope that's the answer to your question. If it's not, please try to re-write the question itself to try to explain the problem a bit more.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I needed. It was simpler than I thought.